# How to Get Current Custom Post Type Associated Taxonomy Term

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, terms

I have a single.php file like below

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
            echo '<div">';
               the_content();
            echo '</div>';
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

now I need to get Current Custom Post Type Associated Taxonomy Term as link on the top of the page so if users click on the link the page navigate to taxonomy.php.

Can you please let me know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// First, get associated taxonomies of the post/object.
$object_taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( get_post() );

// Next, get associated terms of the post/object.
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $object_taxonomies );

$terms = array();
// returned object terms could be WP_Error, so check that first.
if( ! is_wp_error($object_terms) && is_array($object_terms) )
{
    foreach( $object_terms as $object_term )
    {
        // get_term_link could return WP_Error as well, so validate
        $link = get_term_link($object_term);

        if( ! is_wp_error($link) ){
            $terms[] = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $link, $object_term->name);
        }
    }
}

// Lastly, display
if( !empty($terms) ){
    echo join(', ', $terms);
}
```